# Is there a better way to do imports for namespaces in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, namespaces

The following is some sample code using a namespace in typescript:

```
export namespace com.ng.validation {
    export interface StringValidator {
        isAcceptable(s : string) : boolean;
    }

    export class LettersOnlyValidator implements StringValidator {
        lettersRegexp : RegExp;

        constructor() {
            this.lettersRegexp = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
        }

        isAcceptable(str: string) : boolean {
            return this.lettersRegexp.test(str);
        }
    }
}
```

This is some sample code of doing the import of the namespace, and using the LettersOnlyValidator class:

```
import { com } from "./validation/string-validator";

(function() {

    let val : com.ng.validation.StringValidator = new com.ng.validation.LettersOnlyValidator();
    console.log(val.isAcceptable("AB1C"));
})();
```

Imho, This is really ugly code.  Is there any Typescript functionality to import namespace that is similar to this c++ code snippet?:

```
using namespace x::y::z;
```

Comment: Don't mix modules and namespaces. Modules are there to replace namespaces. Namespaces are the way Typescript did things before modules were standardized